# How to solve this error: No best type found for implicitly-typed array

Tags: c#, boolean

Why am I not able to use the boolean parameter in this statement?
It's showing me this error:

> No best type found for implicitly-typed array

```
   public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return new[] { "ABC123", "9999", "9999", "1000", "20180427120717123", false };
}
```

[image: My code]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a mixed array: just don't be vague:

```
yield return new object[] { "ABC123", ..., false }
```

The difference is the `new object[] {...}` instead of `new [] {...}`, which means that the compiler doesn't need to try to figure out what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you want to enumerate `object[]`s:

```
public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator() {
  yield return new object[] { "ABC123", "9999", "9999", "1000", "20180427120717123", false };
  yield return new object[] { "ABC123", "9999", "9999", "1000", "20180427120717123", true };
}
```

Comment: I'm using the IEnumerator inside a class, where I reference it into the Source[] Attribute for a Mock object as part of unit test.